# Rewrite URL so that query string is in path

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the following path: `/faculty/index.php?PID=FirstLast&type=alpha`

To rewrite to this: `/faculty/FirstLast`

Am I correct to assume the following would be acceptable to put in .htaccess?

```
# Rewrite old URLS
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PID=([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$
RewriteRule ^/faculty/index.php$ /faculty/%1 [R=302,L]
```

I'm okay to throw away any other query string variables. I'm applying these rules at the .htaccess file level. This project is a migration from an older system into Drupal.

### Outcome:

My .htaccess looks like

```
  # Rewrite old  URLS
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PID=([0-9a-zA-Z]*)
  RewriteRule ^faculty/ /faculty/%1/? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} vidID=([0-9]*)
  RewriteRule ^videos/ /video/id/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

I also found this wonderful tool -- a mod_rewrite tester 
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

All good!

Comment: you're sure mod_rewrite is enabled and you have 'allow override' for this folder?

Comment: Thanks Joe. Yes, they both appear to work. (As clean URLs in Drupal is working)

Comment: Do you mean the visitor will type in (or click a link for) `/faculty/index.php?PID=FirstLast&type=alpha` and you want to redirect them to `/faculty/FirstLast` or do you mean you want the visitor to be able to type in (or click) `/faculty/FirstLast` and have Apache silently fetch the content of `/faculty/index.php?PID=FirstLast&type=alpha` so that the user only sees the "clean" URL?

Comment: HI Arkanon: We're doing this to keep old book marks active. Yes the visitor will use the first link `servername.edu/faculty/index.php?PID=FirstLast&type=alpha` and I'd like them thrown over to `servername.edu/faculty/FirstLast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^faculty/index.php$ /faculty/%1? [R=302,L]
```

The leading slash is not in the URI-path tested in the rule, so can't be in the regex either.

As the query is automatically appended to the substitution URL (passed through unchanged) unless a new query is created in the rule, the trailing question mark `?` erases the existing query string when the rule is used.